# passing variable to function returns empty list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that does not seem to like a variable I pass it. For example:

```
hostname = 'server_1.local'
domain = 'mydomain.ca'

def get_env(hostname, domain):
    www_path = ["ls /var/www/", domain]
    command = ''.join(www_path)
    print(hostname, domain, command)
    server_response = subprocess.Popen(["ssh" , hostname, command], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    envfile_path_list = server_response.stdout.readlines()
    return envfile_path_list

print(get_env(hostname, domain))
```

The result I get is the *hostname, domain, command* just fine but the list is empty

```
sever_1.local mydomain.ca ls /var/www/mydomain.ca

[]
```

However If I pass the full command in the `subprocess.Popen()` function i get the result as expected

```
def get_env(hostname, domain):
    www_path = ["ls /var/www/", domain]
    command = ''.join(www_path)
    print(hostname, domain, command)
    server_response = subprocess.Popen(["ssh" , hostname, "ls /var/www/mydomain.ca/"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    envfile_path_list = server_response.stdout.readlines()
    return envfile_path_list

print(get_env(hostname, domain))
```

```
sever_1.local mydomain.ca ls /var/www/mydomain.ca

['archive\n', 'site\n', 'verification\n', 'app\n']
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I notice in version 1 the command = "ls /var/www/mydomain.ca" but in version 2 it is "ls /var/www/mydomain.ca/" (notice the slash / ) and because the **ls** command works on directories not files- I presume this is why.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried adding the / to the command var and also omitting it directly on the subprocess.Popen() function but still getting an empty list [] :\

Answer (score 0):

Ok a very smart person help me realized that it was a typo all along. The code I shared here works perfectly fine but the code in my script has the real domain and there was a typo in there. Sorry for the trouble